# Why is my :nth-child(2) selector not working in my jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery:

```
    $(".score-window a:first-child").click(function() {
        $(".score-window").hide();
        $(".login-window").show();
    });

    $(".score-window a:nth-child(2)").click(function() {
        $(".score-window").hide();
        $(".register-window").show();
    });
```

Which is hooked up to the following HTML:

```
        <div class="score-window">
            <i class="icon-remove" title="Close"></i>
            <p>In order to view your score, you have to <a href="#">log in</a>.</p><br>
            <p>Don't have an account yet? <a href="#">Register</a>! Totally free and you'll get the ability to save your scores.</p>
        </div>
```

I only have two links in the `score-window` class, so I don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Note that `nth-of-type` could be more useful here because the first child is `i` and not `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two links, but each one is the only child of its parent `p`, so they will match `a:first-child` only. The parent of the links is not `.score-window`, but `p`. However the parent of the `p` elements (along with the `i` and `br` elements) *is* `.score-window`.

You need to amend your selectors to use `:nth-child()` with the `p` elements instead, then select the `a` under each one. There's an `i` which is the first child, and a `br` between your two `p` elements which looks like it isn't needed. You should be able to remove it then do this:

```
$(".score-window p:nth-child(2) a").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".login-window").show();
});

$(".score-window p:nth-child(3) a").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".register-window").show();
});
```

If the `br` must stay there for whatever reason, use `p:nth-child(4)` or `p:last-child` instead for your second selector.

If you're using or can upgrade to jQuery 1.9, you can use `:nth-of-type()` instead to limit the count to just your `p` elements (i.e. the first `p` and the second `p`), but older versions of jQuery don't support it:

```
$(".score-window p:nth-of-type(1) a").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".login-window").show();
});

$(".score-window p:nth-of-type(2) a").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".register-window").show();
});
```

Comment: Note that `nth-of-type` could be more useful here because the first child is `i` and not `p`.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: True, although it does come with a potential trade-off. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The second link still doesn't work, even if I copy and paste your first solution.

Comment: @Doug Smith: I just noticed that there's a `br` separating your two `p`s, I'm not sure that element is needed. I expanded on that part.

Comment: The br is for formatting (I want another line between the paragraphs) but I changed 3 to 4 and it works now, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have `a` element inside `score-window` element (I mean direct child of `score-window`). Actually its within `p`.

Comment: How don't I? I have one for the log in link and one for the register link.

Comment: Why the down votes? He's actually right! (upvote) there is no `a` that is a direct child of `score-window`.

Comment: It's still a descendant of `.score-window`, which is implied by the word "inside". It's just extremely poorly phrased.

Comment: direct children are selected like `$('#id > a')` and when you write `$('#id a')` all the `a`s within `#id` block are selected.

Answer (score 0):

what u need here is

```
$(".score-window p:nth-child(2) a").click(function() {...});
```

since `a` is child of `<p>` tag and not `<div class="score-window">`....

Answer (score 0):

Use :eq instead, the `a` elements are children of score-window, just not direct ones, so your space syntax is correct. Just :eq instead, because the `a` elements are *not* first children of their direct parents (there's a text node before each), but they are first within the set you're matching. You do *not* need to specify the `p` element in the middle when matching.

```
$(".score-window a:eq(0)").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".login-window").show();
});

$(".score-window a:eq(1)").click(function() {
    $(".score-window").hide();
    $(".register-window").show();
});
```